# Javascript declaring elements of array with conditional operator behaves unexpectedly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, syntax

I'm fairly new to javascript and I saw this issue which I couldn't make any sense of,

Here's the code and inspector output from Chrome,

```
> test?'test':'ok'
"ok"
> [test?'test':'ok']
["ok"]
> ['ok' + test?'test':'ok']
["test"]
```

What is going on with this array? All I want is to create an array 
['browser' + isIE? 'IE' : 'UNKNOWN'].

I could do it with [isIE? 'browser: IE' : 'browser: UNKNOWN'] which works. But I don't understand what is wrong with above syntax?

Comment: Syntax error. Please verify.

Comment: `['browser' + isIE? 'IE' + 'UNKNOWN']` doesn't look right. Should be  `['browser' + isIE ? 'IE' : 'UNKNOWN']` (note the colon `:`)

Comment: Well, what's the value of `test`?

Comment: Thanks rae1n. My mistake fixed the syntax error with question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how the expression is evaluated:

```
('ok' + test) ? 'test' : 'ok';
```

*Evaluate the concatenation of `'ok'` and `test`, return `'test'` if truthy, `'ok'` otherwise.*

What you want is:

```
'ok' + (test ? 'test' : 'ok');
```

*Concatenate `'ok'` with the result of ternary expression, which is `'test'` if `test` is truthy, `'ok'` otherwise*

**Update**

Concrete example. This will return what you want.

```
'browser: ' + (isIE? 'IE' : 'UNKNOWN')
```

I wasn't sure whether you wrapped the expression in square brackets to denote an array or not, but I've left them off here ;-)

Comment: Awesome! this was the issue with expression. Thanks Jack you rock.

Answer (score 5):

You can rewrite `[isIE? 'browser: IE' : 'browser: UNKNOWN']` to:

`["browser: " + (isIE ? 'IE' : 'UNKNOWN') ]`

I would recommend to ***always* use brackets** with the conditional operator.

A common pitfall is: `bool ? "a" : "b" + "c"` will give `"a"` or `"bc"`, but not the intended `"ac"`.

`(bool ? "a" : "b") + "c"` is the intended functionality.

Another pitfall:

`'ok' + test?'test':'ok'` gives `"test"` or `"ok"` but never `"oktest"` or `"okok"`. This is because `'ok' + test` is treated as a boolean (which will always be true I think?).

`'ok' + (test ? 'test' : 'ok')` is the intended functionality.

Comment: And you can overcome this issue by parenthesis like:

`(bool ? "a" : "b") + "c" `

This way you will get either 'ac' or 'bc'.